# How to prevent grid-row span from changing column placement?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a 3 X 3 [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

I have a row in which I have three items `A`, `B` & `C`.

I want item `C` to have a `rowspan` of 2.

To do so, I am using `grid-row: 1 / span 2;`. It is taking two rows, but it's being placed in the first column instead of simply lying in the 3rd column. I don't know why this is happening.

I want item C to stay at the place where it is in the HTML.

One work around to this problem is to explicitly setting `grid-column: 3 / span 1` which I don't want to do. I want items to be placed the way they are in HTML.

Is there any way to suppress this behavior?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: guide grid : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way of solving it (That points to the reason **why** is stating a row for the other items):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: orange;
}

.b {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="b">
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the reason of this behaviour is that the more restrictive elements get positioned first. This way, the possibilities of the grid algorithm to achieve a solution are bigger.

That is, an element that has a requirement will be positioned first, elements that don't have a requirement last.

Steps 2 (for **a** item) and 4 (for the remaining items) in this [part of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo)

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

Comment: I had actually read that section of the spec. I guess I didn't understand it well enough. To be honest, even with your guidance, it's still not completely clear to me. I'll have to read it more carefully this weekend. Thank you.

Comment: It's a pity that my english isn't better. I wish I could explain myself better ...

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If only one gets stock to a row number it will come first and stick there ahead in the flow. To avoid this, other grid items needs to be set to a defaut row as well.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

div {
  grid-row: 1;/* here is the basic fix but will set each item on first row */
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Else you need also to tell in which `grid-column` it should stand

```
.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column:3;
  background: orange;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column:3;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

or let auto placement do its job while only setting how many rows to span, wich is here, **in my own opinion**,  the most flexible way with a minimum of css rules/selector to set, **too much grid kills grid** :) , make it simple :

```
.a {
  grid-row:  span 2;
  background: orange;
}
```

snippet with a few example letting the .aclass do its job without setting the column nor the row number where to stand, it will just be spanning where it stans in the flow

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a {
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>D</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>E</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>F</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>G</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>H</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>B</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>D</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>E</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>F</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>G</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>H</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with `grid-row: span 2` but not able to grok why telling the same thing with specific start taking it to first column. I mean setting `grid-row: 1/span 2`;

Comment: @HiteshKumar What's wrong about setting the column where it should stand ? There also grid-area for that purpose

Comment: @HiteshKumar  an example if you do want to use the `grid-row:1 / span 2 ;`  and elsewhere `grid-row:2 / span 2 ;`  because element can be at  different position (or just many) : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VbzoaJ You cannot do without `grid-column: X ;`

Comment: @GCyrillus, your answer, like mine, solves the problem, but doesn't explain it. It would be good to know ***why*** the `.a` item, which is last in the source, moves to the first column when `grid-row` is set to `1`. I've searched the spec but have come up empty so far. If you find anything please post.

Comment: @Michael_B ... well if grid-column is not enough and unwelcome for that one class element, then you'll need to set a default row where to stand for each grid items, so they remain in the flow at screen as they would stand in HTML .:) (updated answer with an example, but that will break once you have more than 1 row. So should we do a grid-row reset for each item to which row  they are supposed to be ? ) _i guess my english is to poor to go in explanation whenmy free time runs out ;) . Any how, when there is feedback and other answers it always comes positive.

Comment: @HiteshKumar it would be nice to have feed back why you did not want or understood the purpose of grid-column here. The hint was : the browsers sees a grid container where it have to set item into that grid. It search for infos area, coordonates, spanning,etc . it finds one , suppose to stand on row 1 and span 2 rows when others have no restriction. So that one is picked up first because it has coordonate and spanning ... and comes first. the rest will be dispatch in the empty grid cells remaining .

Comment: @HiteshKumar Your question title is _"How to prevent grid-row span from changing column placement?"_ and my very first answer was to tell you to use grid-column to set also coordonate for it , could not be more simple ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus I wanted to understand the behavior why it's happening which Vals has explained in his answer. I think you've also explained the same in comment. Up vote for explanation. Ty :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, there's something in the spec that causes this behavior. I'm not yet sure what it is. (Update: see [@Vals' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43790678/3597276) for an explanation.)

However, here's a valid and simple solution:

Instead of:

```
.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
```

Use:

```
.a {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

*From the spec:*

> [**9.3. Line-based Placement: the `grid-row-start`,
>   `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and `grid-column-end`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)
>
> The `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and
>   `grid-column-end` properties determine a grid item’s size and location
>   within the grid by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic)
>   to its grid placement, thereby specifying the inline-start,
>   block-start, inline-end, and block-end edges of its grid area.
>
> ...
>
> For example, `grid-column-end: span 2` indicates the second grid line
>   in the endward direction from the `grid-column-start` line.

---

Also, consider this single rule that gives you full control and makes it all work:

```
.a {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 /  3 / 4;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhxsuzxy/)

The [**`grid-area`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands) shorthand property parses values in this order:

- `grid-row-start`
- `grid-column-start`
- `grid-row-end`
- `grid-column-end`

Note the counter-clockwise direction, which is the opposite of `margin` and `padding`.

Comment: `grid-row-end: span 2` would only work so long as the grid is one row in height, correct?

Comment: No. The grid can have as many rows (*explicit* or *implicit*) as you want. `grid-row-end: span 2` simply tells the item to span two `end` grid lines.

Comment: Also, I added another approach you may want to consider.

Comment: I have added an answer with what I believe is the reason of this behaviour .

Comment: @Michael_B Right, but if you want the placement to start at row 1, and there are 3 or 4 rows, then using `grid-row-end: span 2` would mean it doesn't start at row 1 anymore. At least that's how I am seeing it (I haven't fully read thru the Grids spec yet)

Comment: @TylerH, there are actually three rows in the layout in question. `grid-row-end` does appear to work as I indicated. Check the fiddle in my answer. Here's a copy: https://jsfiddle.net/uhxsuzxy/