# How do I make flex items fit the height of two rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a special  in a row of flexboxes stretch to be the height of two rows. Here is what I am trying to achieve:
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPM0m.png). But here is my current result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JpgO.png).

I think I have to use `flex-wrap: wrap;`, but I am not sure. I don't want to do `flex-direction: column;`, because then I cannot stretch the divs at the top like if they were aligned in a row. I want all the children divs to be part of the same flex container. Does anyone have any ideas?

*Note : I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container), where I was able to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xOxN.png). If somehow I can move the Three up to be next to the Two, I may be able to achieve what I want. Not sure how to do this.*

Here is my code I am using:

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>This box has little text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small and middleish. It has a lot of text. Thus, I want it to continue onto the next row of flexboxes.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>This box has little text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: does all `.flex-col` has to be direct children of `.flex-row` ?

Comment: Yes, I would like all the `.flex-col` to be inside the same flex- container.

Comment: Then your best bet is to use CSS Grid, because flex can go in one direction at a time.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bhteu14a/) of css grid achieving what you wanted easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) like this.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.tall {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.grid-box {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-box">
    <p>This box has little text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box tall">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small and middleish. It has a lot of text. Thus, I want it to continue onto the next row of flexboxes.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box">
    <p>This box has little text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me this `grid-column: 3;` isn't it the third column from the start ? , and why it goes to column 1 when you remove it ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak There's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43790678/5385381

Comment: And the difference between `grid-row: 1 / 3;` and `grid-row: span 2;` ? cuz if you use the later you don't have to specify the column.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap 2 divs with a wrapper div. That should do the trick.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-col {
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.double {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="double">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <p>This box has little text.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      <p>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="double">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <p>This box is diffrent than small and middleish. It has a lot of text. Thus, I want it to continue onto the next row of flexboxes.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      <p>This box has little text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make the ones aligned in a row to be the height of one of the items in `.flex-col double`?

Comment: I fixed my answer, please check again

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, `table` solution:

```css
table {border-spacing: 10px}

td {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This box has little text.</td>
    <td>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</td>
    <td rowspan="2">This box is diffrent than small and middleish. It has a lot of text. Thus, I want it to continue onto the next row of flexboxes.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This box has little text.</td>
    <td>This box is diffrent than small. It has a middleish amout of text.</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```